# Taking output from an Adafruit I2C 16 channel driver

Tags: arduino, hardware, microcontroller, arduino-ide

Hello I'm struggling to read output values from an Adafruit '16 Channel Driver'. Excuse me if my vocab isn't appropriate.

The project is to wire a HC-SRO4 ultrasonic sensor to an Arduino through Adafruit's '16 channel I2C driver'. For this circuit to work I need to write and read values through the I2C driver.

Naturally the HC-SRO4 ultrasonic sensor has a VCC, GND, **TRIG** and **ECHO** pin. To run the sensor I increase and decrease the values on the TRIG, then monitor the signal response through the ECHO pin.

The problem is that I can't write or read digital values through the I2C. I'd love to use  writeDigital or pulseIn, but their addressing system doesn't seem to extend to the driver's address's.

I've tried rewriting the pulseIn library-standard function to read the hexidecimal address of the I2C board.

```
unsigned long pulseIn2(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, unsigned long timeout)
    {
    // cache the port and bit of the pin in order to speed up the
    // pulse width measuring loop and achieve finer resolution.  calling
    // digitalRead() instead yields much coarser resolution.
    uint8_t bit = pin;
    uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(pin);
    uint8_t stateMask = (state ? bit : 0);
    unsigned long width = 0; // keep initialization out of time critical area

    // convert the timeout from microseconds to a number of times through
    // the initial loop; it takes 16 clock cycles per iteration.
    unsigned long numloops = 0;
    unsigned long maxloops = microsecondsToClockCycles(timeout) / 16;

    // wait for any previous pulse to end
    while ((*portInputRegister(port) & bit) == stateMask)
        if (numloops++ == maxloops)
            return 0;

    // wait for the pulse to start
    while ((*portInputRegister(port) & bit) != stateMask)
        if (numloops++ == maxloops)
            return 0;

    // wait for the pulse to stop
    while ((*portInputRegister(port) & bit) == stateMask) {
        if (numloops++ == maxloops)
            return 0;
        width++;
    }

    // convert the reading to microseconds. The loop has been determined
    // to be 20 clock cycles long and have about 16 clocks between the edge
    // and the start of the loop. There will be some error introduced by
    // the interrupt handlers.
    return clockCyclesToMicroseconds(width * 21 + 16);
   }
```

I thought this would work for function calls that use I2C addresses

```
   pulseIn2(0x41, HIGH);
```

But that totally didn't work. My question is- Is there an easier way to address pins through the I2C? I need a way to read and write values easily- and use standard functions like *pulseIn*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't even know what manual I would FRTM for.

http://www.adafruit.com/product/815

Comment: You need to use the I2C Arduino library which is called "Wire" http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire